# Osmdroid and marshmallow

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using `osmdroid 5.2` lib in `android 6.0`. I'm asking `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and ACCESS_COARSE / FINE_LOCATION permissions on realtime`.
 But map not working:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/osmdroid/tiles/Mapnik/14/10079/5358.png.tile: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Map works only from the second run application. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you also specify those permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Please try to explain more what you tried, there are too many possibilities the problem could come from.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask for the permissions before the mapview is loaded and displayed.

Either that, or the path is read only. On some android devices `Environment.getExternalStorageDir` returns a read only partition. No clue why, but that will definitely cause issues. It can be overridden with the class `OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants`